# When do I need to use include() and when I don't?

Tags: django, python-3.x, url, django-urls, django-1.9

What is the difference of using `include()` in a URL. I'm using Django 1.9.

Comment: Er, you use it when you want to include some other urls. What's confusing you?

Comment: `urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]`

sometimes I may use it, sometimes I may not use it, right? What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`include()` is used when you have an urls.py in your app directory. In this case it means "import" urls from the urls.py from the app directory into the "central" urls.py in your project directory.

If you don't have the urls.py file or you are not using it in your app dir then you don't use the `include()`.

Is that clear for you?

Comment: You are welcome, do not forget to mark this answer as helpful :P

Answer (score 0):

`admin.site.urls` does some things that are deprecated in Django 1.9, but are needed in the admin to maintain backwards compatibility. To avoid warnings, it is recommended to use `admin.site.urls` instead of `include(admin.site.urls)`.

In every other case where you include other URL patterns, use `include()`.